# UIImageView dimensions not what I set in IB

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I set a UIImageView to 70x70 pixels. In the actual view they look 70px high and 30 wide. This is when there is no source UIImage set and with a background color so I can see it's layout. However, when I do set a UIImage to it the layout does not change, remains portrait.

Is there something I am overlooking that affects the layout dimensions of a UIImage or UIImageView?

Thanks.

Comment: You didn't mention the "mode" that is set for the view above, that's a likely culprit.

In IB in the inspector for the UIImageView it's called "mode" there are various options which will stretch and shape the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NWcoder's comment sounds like a reasonable answer to what was going on here. Also, Siddiqui mentioned the frame which can be used to override the layout, but since so much time has passed since I ad this question, I won't confirm or deny. Just assuming based on logic.

I'm answering my own question to close this question out as best as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the frame this may be fix your problem.